# Why my CSS global style sheet is being overridden by local style sheet in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

My React project file structure is

```
-src
    |
     - components 
    |           | 
    |            - {My various components and a custom.css file}
     - App.css
```

Now whenever I apply my custom.css file which have some attributes that are flagged as `!important` , The same styles are being applied globally. Is there any way to escape it.

Comment: Are you including your local style sheet inside the main JS file? For example, `import "./index.css";`?

Comment: @TannerDolby I am including it exclusively in the component that needed those styles.

Comment: @TannerDolby quite lengthy.